# What does the "Media" item type contain

Tags: ingress

In your Ops>Item area, there's an item type filter marked "Media". What kind of stuff shows up there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far I have only documents, some top secret investigation documents. They are dropped out of portals when you hack them.

So far you can only open and drop them, so no idea what to do with them yet. When opened, they link you to an online resource page like the Niantic project page.

Comment: How did you get them? What's in them?

Comment: Is Ingress open for registering ?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins as far as I know not yet, but you can sign up for an invite.

Comment: From some conversations I think that the media contains hints to passcodes that grant AP/XM/items

Answer (score 1):

Media do contains passcodes for some items, AP and XM. You need to decode the media to get the passcodes. If you'll search on google, you'll find various method on how to decode them. Although one method may or may not apply to other media.